# SQL Server function error - conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_InventoryPositionSet]
(
    @PointInTime DATETIME,
    @EOD BIT,
    @AccountList Varchar(max)
)
RETURNS @OffersTable TABLE
(
    Account            VARCHAR(10),
    PositionId         VARCHAR(150),
    VersionDate        DATETIME,
    ProductType        VARCHAR(50),
    XRef               VARCHAR(50),
    XRefType           VARCHAR(20),
    Desk               VARCHAR(50)

)
AS
BEGIN
    IF @EOD = 1 
        SET @PointInTime = dbo.COBTimestamp(@PointInTime)

    IF @AccountList is not NULL     
                INSERT INTO @OffersTable
                SELECT      
                    P.Account,
                    P.UniquePositionId AS [PositionId],
                    P.Desk,
                    P.VersionEffective AS [VersionDate],
                    P.ProductType,
                    P.XRef,
                    P.XRefType
                FROM MarkingInventory AS P WITH(nolock)
                LEFT JOIN 
                    Spirit.dbo.GetTableOfInputs(@AccountList) A 
                    ON 
                        ( 
                            (P.Account = A.Input)
                            AND 
                            @AccountList IS NOT NULL 
                        )
                WHERE 
                    @PointInTime >= P.VersionEffective AND @PointInTime < P.VersionExpiration and P.Account = A.Input
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO @OffersTable
                SELECT      
                    P.Account,
                    P.UniquePositionId AS [PositionId],
                    P.Desk,
                    P.VersionEffective AS [VersionDate],
                    P.ProductType,
                    P.XRef,
                    P.XRefType
                FROM MarkingInventory AS P WITH(nolock)
                WHERE 
                    @PointInTime >= P.VersionEffective AND @PointInTime < P.VersionExpiration 

RETURN
END
```

I have created this function which takes in three parameters. I have couple of questions regarding execution of this function.

> *Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string*

This is the error I receive when I try to execute this function in following manner

```
select * from [dbo].[fn_InventoryPositionSet] (GETDATE(), 1, null)
```

It fails even when I pass `2012-03-10` instead of `getdate()`

I also want to learn how to pass parameters in the form of list. As one of the parameter is in form of a list. Let me know if you want some more information about the function.

This is a function which is used in the function written above:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[COBTimestamp]
(
    @COBDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @COBDate), '23:59:59')             

END
GO
```

Comment: '23:59:59' this can't be converted to `DATETIME`. Also correct tags.

Comment: Corrected tags . Will take a look into your explanation . Thanks

Comment: `PL/SQL` hasn't `DATEADD` function. I assume you use `SQL Server`.

Comment: Correct i am using SQl Server.

Comment: You are asking about two very different things. It would be better to ask them in separate questions. Also, your second question [has been asked many times](http://www.google.com/cse?cx=018205968162215846785%3A7n6ajnwyz-i&ie=UTF-8&q=sql+server+pass+multiple+values&sa=Search).

Comment: Is either `P.VersionEffective` or `P.VersionExpiration` a `varchar`?

Comment: Hello Andriy M , P.VersionEffective and P.VersionExpiration are datetime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your table definition:

```
1. Account            VARCHAR(10),
2. PositionId         VARCHAR(150),
*** 3. VersionDate        DATETIME, ***
4. ProductType        VARCHAR(50),
5. XRef               VARCHAR(50),
6. XRefType           VARCHAR(20),
7. Desk               VARCHAR(50)
```

And your SELECT:

```
            SELECT      
                1. P.Account,
                2. P.UniquePositionId AS [PositionId],
                *** 3. P.Desk, ***
                4. P.VersionEffective AS [VersionDate],
                5. P.ProductType,
                6. P.XRef,
                7. P.XRefType
```

Comment: Thanks This worked. I did a mistake in my table definition and my select query.

Answer (score 0):

The problem not in `[dbo].[fn_InventoryPositionSet]` it is in `[dbo].[COBTimestamp]`.

```
RETURN DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, @COBDate), '23:59:59')
                                                    ^__________ Must be converted to `DATETIME`
```

**[DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx)**

Comment: You don't need to comment any lines,you must pass correct argument to `DATEADD` function.

Comment: The `'23:59:59'` bit [poses no problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/10699) in SQL Server.